# When should we change the name to include fantasy?

Tags: discussion, status-completed, fantasy

When should we change the name to include fantasy? I'm pretty sure that it's very much in, there are few dissenting votes from either the sci-fi or the fantasy community, but what day should we set for the target date?

Also, I'm assuming the name will be just Science Fiction and Fantasy, if there are any other clever ideas, let's hear them.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Should we change the name of this site to include fantasy?](http://meta.scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/205/should-we-change-the-name-of-this-site-to-include-fantasy). Also see [Is Fantasy in spec for this site?](http://meta.scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/6/is-fantasy-in-spec-for-this-site). You don't need to ask a new question for each slight rephrasing of the question.

Comment: @Mark - I would tend to disagree...the other questions are addressing whether or not we *should*.  As it's been somewhat decided that that answer is "Yes", asking when would be the best time for that seems like a valid next step.

Comment: @morganpdx - agreed, this is *not* a duplicate. This is entirely about *when*. The merge decision has already been made.

Comment: @MarkTrapp: The three questions, while related, are distinct. The first asked if we should allow it, the answer was if it comes up, it's fine, but discourage it with the name. The second was should we change the name, to which there was overwhelmingly positive reaction, but some doubt as to if now is the right time. Thus this post to decide when is the right time. If they all were combined into one thread, then it would get very hard to follow...

Answer (score 13, accepted):

**Now.**

Seriously, why not? I've read the arguments for delaying (e.g. "we could destroy a fantasy Q&A as well if this does not succeed") but by increasing our audience we increase our chances.

Another argument is along the lines of "we need time for this proposal to settle" but I think we're better off doing that *now* **with the fans of fantasy**. After all, they will have a say as well and they're not going to be happy if we say after a couple of months (in response to their questions), "nope, we've decided all that already - you just have to fit in".

So, right now is my answer.

Answer (score 8):

The Science Fiction Stack Exchange has now been officially renamed **"Science Fiction & Fantasy"**. The appropriate logo changes are pending.